# How to generate Allure2 report for Xunit.net project

Tags: report, asp.net-core-2.0, xunit.net, allure

Does Allure2 support xunit project? I do not find it in the Allure2 documentation https://docs.qameta.io/allure/2.0/ But is there some adapter to implement it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allure2 does support xunit project. It does not require special adapter. Allure2 has inbuilt plugin [trx-plugin and xunit-xml-plugin](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/tree/master/plugins).
Steps taken for .netcore2 xunit test project using allure-commandline.

Refer to the [docs to install allure commandline](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_installing_a_commandline)

> Mac OS X [brew](/questions/tagged/brew) `brew install allure`
>
> Windows [scoop](/questions/tagged/scoop)  `scoop install allure`
>
> Linux for debian-based repositories a PPA is provided
>
> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:qameta/allure
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install allure
> ```

#### TRX report

1. Generated output xunit trx report with command: `dotnet test --logger:trx`
2. [Generate Allure report](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_report_generation) with command: `allure serve /home/path/to/project/target/surefire-reports/`

#### XML Report

1. Add a reference to the [Xunit Logger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XunitXml.TestLogger/2.0.0) nuget package in test project.
2. Generate output xunit xml report with command: dotnet test --logger:xunit
3. Generated Allure report with command: allure serve /home/path/to/project/target/surefire-reports/